# Bounded knapsack - formulation

Tags: knapsack-problem

I need to map an optimization problem to a bounded knapsack problem.

I have a set of items, each with a given value vi. All my items have the same weight (wi  = 1) :

- Item 1 =>  v1 : 2,  w1 : 1
- Item 2 =>  v2 : 3, w2 : 1
- Item 3 => v3 :4, w3 :1
- etc.

In my knapsack I can put the same item multiple times (bounded Knapsack) with the constraint that the number of items added to the knapsack cannot exceed *c* (and, hence, each item cannot be added more than c times).

The problem is that the value assigned to an item is dependent on the previous content of the bag : each time an item is added to knapsack, its value is divided by the number of occurrence of the item in the bag. For example, if item 1 is added two times to the knapsack, its value must be decreased to v1/2. If it is added 3 times, its value became v1/3, and so on.

My question is how can I modelize this as a (0-1) knapsack problem and is there a DP solution for that?

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far for this homework problem?

Comment: To transform le problem to a 0-1 knapsack, i consider each item several (i.e. c times) times with different values (v1/1, v1/2, v/3, …, v1/c).

As I must know the content of the bag at each step (in order to assign the right value to the current item), i’m considering using a branch & bound approach.

Is there a better solution (a greedy or a DP solution).

*this is not a homework (I've been out of school for a long time :) )